# JQuery continuously change span color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there a more elegant solution to change a spans color continiously (green, black, green, black etc...) in a smooth manner?

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('#migrate_stamp').animate({ backgroundColor: '#000000' }, 'slow');
   $('#migrate_stamp').animate({ backgroundColor: '#00B312' }, 'slow');
}, 1000);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can set up a couple of functions to call each other as callbacks, but I'm not sure it's more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this -

```
function change(){
  $('#migrate_stamp').animate({ backgroundColor: '#000000' }, 'slow',function(){
     $('#migrate_stamp').animate({ backgroundColor: '#00B312' }, 'slow',change);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems a little more elegant, I couldn't be bothered to create new css selectors, otherwise I would have used:

var el = $('div');
setInterval(function() {
   el.toggleClass('blinking');
}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var el = $('span');
setInterval(function() {
   el.toggleClass('blinking');
}, 1000);
```

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/gLEuP/146/